# App inventor 2 using TinyDB to store value

Tags: android, app-inventor

I am creating an android app using **App Inventor 2**, i want to create a Q&A game that can store players' marks using `TinyDB`.

I have 4 screens
 
- Home Screen
- Q&A screen - Game over
- Player name input
- Leaderboard

After the player has lost the game, then the game will show their marks, and require players to input their name. And then, the player's name will be stored in TinyDB. When the player starts a new game(didn't close the app), again, if he has lost the game, he needs to input his name, and then his marks and name will be stored in `TinyDB`. Now there should be two records stored in TinyDB. When the player goes to Leaderboard, he should be able to see his marks and names (Totally two records now).

I have created a `TinyDB`, **but somehow the old record will be replaced by the new record. It can't store two records.**

Here are my codes for player input

[image]

The codes for Leaderboard

[image]

Edited code in Leaderboard

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the `Leaderboard.Initialize` event you should read the result from `TinyDB` using the `TinyDB.GetValue` block and assign it to the global variable `marksList`.

Your `startvalue` in the `Leaderboard.Initialize` event is only a sublist to be added to the marksList later in your procedure `procedure` and is not the complete list itself. Btw. you might want to rename that `procedure`, for example into `insertMarks`...

Also probably a good idea would be to learn how to work with lists and lists of lists... See here

- [How to work with Lists](http://www.imagnity.com/tutorials/app-inventor/list-blocks-on-app-inventor/) by Saj
- [How to work with Lists and Lists of
  lists](http://www.appinventor.org/bookChapters/chapter19.pdf) (pdf) by [appinventor.org](http://www.appinventor.org/)

Comment: Can you tell what should i do in my case?? Even i have used TinyDB to get value, it only has one value too.

Comment: well, at the beginning, TinyDB does not have any value... you might want to edit your question and add an updated screenshot...

Comment: if you want to get a value from `TinyDB`, then you  should use the `TinyDB.GetValue` block and **not** the `TinyDB.StoreValue` block. I recommend you to read my answer carefully again...